# Public API keys for client-side app for own API and API Gateway

Tags: javascript, api, security, oauth, api-gateway

Examples I see for using public APIs with a client side (JavaScript) app, which still require some form of authorization through an API key or machine-to-machine OAuth flow (client_credentials, for example) will introduce a server component that calls the API, like a nodejs "wrapper" API that the client app talks to, to hide the API keys.

For my situation, I am also creating the API, and hosting it in my own API Gateway. Is there any point in introducing a server side component to hide the API Keys? The API Gateway will throttle usage.  Couldn't a bad actor hit my "wrapper" API just like hitting the API in the gateway for the same net effect? Do I care about exposing the public keys? What is the best practice here?

Comment: Only you can answer whether someone else obtaining public keys/api keys and hitting your API is a problem or not.

Comment: @Evert it's a public api. Looking for correct way to offer a public api. And to understand how wrapping it with a backend service that holds the key is any better than leaving wide open

Comment: If you don't have user accounts or any means of authentication, then adding some api key system just sounds like extra work. Think of your API as a website that emits JSON instead of HTML. What would your website need?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you should think in terms of the data you are hosting. Is it public data? or does it need to be protected?

If it is public, then why have an API and API keys? Is there an easier method to display the data?

If the data should be kept safe then use a proper authentication mechanism, use the API Keys for back-end comms only, don't expose them to the client side and most certainly don't expose them to the public.

That is my 2c.